# Wordpress: add input box values in mailto body text

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to create a simple form which collects four items of info to send via the users own email to a supplier to request permission for 3rd party access to some of their data.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWFs5.jpg)

Your Name: 
Farm Supply Number 1: 
Farm Supply Number 2: 
Farm Supply Number 3:

Email your supplier here

Could you please advise how I can insert the text

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any code we can work on?

Comment: No thank you. Just looking for a bit of guidance.

Comment: Then please clarify the text insertion you're talking about

Comment: I am looking to collect data from input boxes and then use this text in the body of the email. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking if from here: `I am looking to collect data from input boxes and then use this text in the body of the email. Thank you.` I wrote the following for you:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $supplier1 = $_POST['supplier1'];
        $supplier2 = $_POST['supplier2'];
        $supplier3 = $_POST['supplier3'];

        $to = "your_email@gmail.com"; // example, fill in your own
        $subject = "Mail sent from the form on the website by ".$name;
        $message = $name." has sent in the following suppliers:\r\nSupplier 1: ".$supplier1."\r\nSupplier 2: ".$supplier2."\r\nSupplier 3:".$supplier3;

        mail($to, $subject, $message);
        echo "E-mail has been sent."
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="name">Your name : </label><input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    <label for="supplier1">Farm supply number 1 : </label><input type="number" name="supplier1" required><br>
    <label for="supplier2">Farm supply number 2 : </label><input type="number" name="supplier2" required><br>
    <label for="supplier3">Farm supply number 3 : </label><input type="number" name="supplier3" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here to send e-mail"
</form>
```

If anything doesn't work, let me know, I didn't test this.

If you want to add security then use things like the [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

You will get things like

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">`

and

`$supplier1 = htmlentities($_POST['supplier1']);`

You could also add some extra security on checking if the fields are actually filled in before sending, I used `required` on the html, but this is no guarantee. I would also suggest you let people fill in any information so that you can contact them, like e-mail or phone.

Have more information here:

- [Using PHP_SELF](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html)
- [PHP Mail function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)
- [HTML Form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

Comment: Hi Matthijs, Many thanks for this. I have adapted it and it is working OK. Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help, but my advise would be: be sure to understand the code, not just copy paste it ;) Ps. It would be nice if you accepted my answer as the correct one, it gives points which keeps this community running, thanks.